# how to call appengine servlet from browser

Tags: java, google-app-engine, url, servlets, browser

I have an App-Engine servlet that I am trying to call from the browser. But I always get `Not Found`. I think the problem is that I don't know what the url is exactly. My setup is **verified** correct (blobstore has no problem reaching my servlets: **I** just don't know how to do it through browser).

```
<servlet>         <servlet-name>SeePicture</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>com.company.servlet.SeePicture</servlet-class>
     </servlet>     
<servlet-mapping>     
    <servlet-name>SeePicture</servlet-name>     
    <url-pattern>/seepicture/*</url-pattern>     
</servlet-mapping>
```

the call is a get call, and here are the calls I have tried

- `https://company.appspot.com/_ah/api/seepicture/?picid=12345660123456`
- `https://company.appspot.com/_ah/api/v1/server/seepicture/?picid=12345660123456`
- `https://company.appspot.com/_ah/api/1/server/seepicture/?picid=12345660123456`

Comment: Why are you using an `/_ah/api` prefix to your routes? Is you application configured that way? try https://company.appspot.com/seepicture/?picid=12345660123456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<url-pattern>`s should be accessible off of your root domain so you do not need the `/_ah/api` prefix.

Try:

`https://company.appspot.com/seepicture/?picid=12345660123456`